# should images be sent from server to client or stay on client

Tags: java, swing, security, server, client

i'm making a blackjack game in java,
and i'm not sure whether i should send the images of the cards from the server to the client every time or just put all the images files in the client and just use their names.

on the one hand sending the images might make the programming a bit messier and make the program run a little slower,
but on the other hand i don't want to let the client be able to mess up things from his side.
this code isn't for production but it's important for me to put emphasis on security and stability.

i'll be glad to hear your opinions, thanks :)

Comment: By any chance do you want to plan and let client provide their own images as cards? Like custom theme? If yes then leaving on client makes sense. You can always copy/download in first run/install.

Comment: Stackoverflow is meant to help you assist in solving coding problems in of existing code, not in discussing designs. Maybe https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ is a better place for this kind of question.

Comment: The answer is yes and no. Why? Because it depends on so much more context as to what you want to achieve.  Do you want to provide the user with a selection of pack designs, which might be updated over time? For example. These kind of design decisions will effect how you manage this side of things.  If your downloading the images from the server, you should consider caching them, so you don't need to download them each time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track. If you send the images, it will slow down your app and make the code more complicated. If you load the images from a local repo, a user could replace those files with their own images.

If you are focusing on security, you could put the files locally and encrypt them. It would be difficult (read: impossible) to replace the files with images that decrypt properly without the key. An attacker however could switch cards (ie. replace an ace with a 10 just by changing file names). To avoid this, instead of just encrypting the message encrypt the tuple (card value, image). That way you can verify after decrypting that the value is the one you expected. This is all well and good given no one knows the key used to encrypt / decrypt. Therefore, you will need to hide the key (send it over the network, hide it in memory, etc). Also, encryption and decryption does take time, so it will slow down your app. This won't be as noticeable as when you are sending images over the network, but it will be there.

If you go down the path of sending the images, there is still a possible attack vector. An attacker could intercept the network packages and send a different image to your client. To avoid this, you will want to use an encrypted protocol. Many common protocols have encryption options.

Comment: and what if the server won't use any information sended from the client except his actions(double, pass in blackjack)?
i mean what if the server is managing the cards and values, and the client just gets the images names and shows it to the player, and the client sends his move?
in this case if the client changes a picture name the image will only change in his side, am i wrong?

Comment: @heapoverflow yes and no. They would in theory only be able to change the pictures on their side, but if that is all you care about, loading the image from a local or remote source doesn't matter. The result of both is just changing the image on their screen. Think of an online casino. You could change the pics so it looks like you should have won, but lost. Then ask for a refund. Also, image libraries are not incredibly secure, meaning they could load an image which breaks the jpg library and runs arbitrary code. That is how viruses are hidden in some ads online.

Comment: Note that you can't "hide the key" as it needs to be used to decrypt whatever is received. The client has the key and can do whatever it wants with it, eg. it can encrypt a new deck (if it's a symmetric key - if not, the attacker can replace the one on the client with one that he has both the private and public part). TL;DR: this can't be done securely. The user has full control of the client and anything given to the client.

Comment: @Gabor Yeah. It is in user space. They can attach a debugger and do whatever they want. We are attempting to make this as secure as possible and show that we have thought through attack vectors. If they can use a debugger, they can change the execution pointer and run arbitrary code, so worrying about them grabbing it out of memory isn't really what we should be focused on.